# How to get the ref value in Higher order component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component where i am passing the ref value. I need to get the passed ref value in Higher Order component.
Here is the code example:
Component wrapped with HOC:

```
import React from "react";
import HOC from './hoc';
const MeasuredInput = () => {
  const ref = React.createRef();
  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={ref}>Click me!</button>
    </div>
  )
};
export default HOC(MeasuredInput);
```

Higher Order Component:

```
import React from "react";
const HigherOrderFunction = (OriginalComponent) => {
  function NewComponent(props) {
    const { forwardedRef } = props;
    return <OriginalComponent ref={forwardedRef} {...props} />;
  }
  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <NewComponent {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />;
  });
};
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create the `ref` in the HOC and pass it down, not the other way around. Data flows down and HOC is wrapping the component.

```
import React from "react";
const HigherOrderFunction = (OriginalComponent) => {
  return function(props) {
    const ref = useRef();
    return <OriginalComponent ref={ref} {...props} />
  }
};
```

Original Component:

```
import React from "react";
import HOC from './hoc';
const MeasuredInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={ref}>Click me!</button>
    </div>
  )
});
export default HOC(MeasuredInput);
```